# Run Selenium Python script without headless mode on Linux Server

Tags: linux, python, webserver, chrome, selenium

I have a script that I want to run on Linux server That script downloads CSV file from amazon after log in. I have achieved the goal with **Chrome web driver (Chromium) using selenium in Python**. My question is that Can I run this script on Linux **server without headless mode**? because when I run script in headless mode the file doesn't download.

Answer (score 1):

If your server does not have a graphical environment, you will need to run Chromium in headless mode. Debugging can be a little bit of a struggle because you cannot directly see what selenium does.

Useful pointers:

- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23447450/7350091) helped me a lot to setup my first headless selenium script
- You may try firefox headless driver. I've seen cases where it worked when Chromium didn't (you will need the [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases))
- You can prepare a first version of your Selenium script on a machine where you have a graphical environment and then migrate the script to your headless environment
- As for debugging, I usually dump the visited web pages at different points to see where the script fails (good old "print" debugging)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pyvirtualdisplay` to run your chromdriver in zero display on your server. 
Here is the complete answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59793651/6903322

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Whilst this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.